# Inconsistent results with sphinxcontrib-spelling (Windows vs. Ubuntu)

Tags: python, python-sphinx, spell-checking

I am using the sphinx with sphinx.contrib to do spell checking for my documentation.
I get different results when running the spell check locally (Windows 10) and running it on my CI/CD GitLab machine (Ubuntu).
Both are running the same version of python + libraries.

My pipeline is as follow:

```
- sudo apt-get install software-properties-common -y
- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y
- sudo apt-get update -y
- sudo apt-get install python3.8 python3.8-dev python3.8-venv python3-pip python3-venv python-enchant -y
- python3.8 -mvenv ../myenv
- source ../myenv/bin/activate
- python3.8 -mpip install --upgrade  pip
- python3.8 -mpip install -U sphinx sphinx-sitemap sphinx-last-updated-by-git sphinxcontrib-bibtex sphinxcontrib-spelling
- python3.8 -mpip install -U --force-reinstall sphinx-aimms-theme
- python3.8 -msphinx -W --keep-going -b spelling . _build/spelling
```

My conf.py file has a language configuration to avoid any differences between machines:

```
spelling_lang='en_US'
```

The word check on the Linux machine seems to be more consistent than locally since my current branch has 0 misspelled words locally and 32 on the CI/CD (with some obvious mistakes that aren't being detected locally).

I tried running both on python3.10 and updating all libraries, but I get the same results. I do use a custom word list to ignore certain words, but none of the 32 misspelled are on this list.

Is there any limit to checking locally? Is it ignoring certain files? I am at a loss as to why there is a difference.

My branch isn't available yet, but the same behaviour can be found in the Master branch of the original repository which can be found here: https://github.com/aimms/documentation

I tested with commit 7c2103843ead3bdaa728ae56eab968c3f147f520

CI/CD Linux build:

```
WARNING: Found 1292 misspelled words
build finished with problems, 1 warning.
```

Local Windows build:

```
WARNING: Found 1608 misspelled words
build finished with problems, 40 warnings.
```

Comment: hard to say , since there is no detail provided , my only guess is that some default settings are different on your local and the linux machine

Comment: I just added the repository that is available on GitHub. Please let me know if there is any additional information that would be useful.

Comment: Did you install PyEnchant? sphinxcontrib.spelling uses it to produce a report showing misspelled words: https://sphinxcontrib-spelling.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Yes. I have the list of misspelled words and they don't match between the local build and the CI/CD. For example, CI/CD outputs the following 
`/home/jenkins/builds/bC1WuhGZ/0/aimms/documentation/webui/widget-manager.rst:64: Spell check: ae: The '[]' characters function as a 'whichever one of these' operator. So, searching for 'l[ae]g' will result in all strings that contain the substrings 'lag' or 'leg'..`
But in the local spell check build, this is not in its report.